# Retornar valor de expressão regular

Tags: php, regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
[11:36:19] Touched down at -56 fpm, gear lever: down, pitch: 3, roll: level, 116 kts
```

E estou tentando uma expressão regular para pegar o valor 116 kts, sendo que a string não tem um número de palavras fixa.

A minha expressão é essa:

```
\[([0-9:]+)\] Touched down at -[0-9]+ fpm, gear lever: down, pitch: 3, roll: level, [0-9]+ kts/
```

Porém os valores pitch e roll nem sempre aparecem, e o que gera o erro.

Comment: E essa expressão? `\d+(?=\s*kts)` e o debug do [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XUJTHG/1). Usando positive lookahead `?=`

Comment: Se a idéia é usar _positive lookahead_ para ver se os números `\d+` são seguidos de possível espaço e a string kts, por que não simplesmente `\d\s*kts`? Não que seja contra o _lookahead_, haha, só acho que às vezes aumenta a complexidade da regex desnecessariamente, e não é uma funcionalidade suportada em todo lugar (embora no presente caso, que é [tag:php], sim). +1 porque mostrou o Regex101, não conhecia! =D

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa especificar a linha inteira na expressão se você quer o valor de "kts", a expressão `([0-9]+) kts` (um ou mais numeros seguidos de " kts") é suficiente para essa linha. No PHP use a função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) e passe um array para servir de saída:

```
$linha = '[11:36:19] Touched down at -56 fpm, gear lever: down, pitch: 3, roll: level, 116 kts';
$saida = array();
preg_match('/([0-9]+) kts/', $linha, $saida);
echo $saida[1];

116
```

Todos os valores marcados com parênteses na expressão regular (o chamado "grupo de captura", ou *rematch*) serão retornados no array. O item `$saida[0]` contém sempre o texto que casa com a expressão toda. Assim, dá para popular um só array com todos os dados que você quiser extrair:

```
$linha = '[11:36:19] Touched down at -56 fpm, gear lever: down, pitch: 3, roll: level, 116 kts';
$saida = array();
preg_match('/\[([0-9:]+)\] .* ([-+0-9]+) fpm, gear lever: ([a-z]+), pitch: ([0-9]+), roll: ([a-z]+), ([0-9]+) kts/', $linha, $saida);
print_r($saida);

Array
(
    [0] => [11:36:19] Touched down at -56 fpm, gear lever: down, pitch: 3, roll: level, 116 kts
    [1] => 11:36:19
    [2] => -56
    [3] => down
    [4] => 3
    [5] => level
    [6] => 116
)
```

Exemplo do PHP no repl.it: https://repl.it/M0qa/1

Exemplo da segunda expressão regular no regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ZXMq6Y/1